# CreateAmazonS3Client uses cached appSettings always?

Tags: c#, .net, aws-sdk

I use this constructor to create S3 Client first:

```
var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(config);
```

From AWS documentation I know the client credential comes from the  in my app.config.

However I need to update the config on the fly after first usage and already use following code to refresh app config:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

However the new S3 Client created still use the old AWSAccessKey & AWSSecretKey. Is it because of cache? If so, how I can work around it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(new EnvironmentAWSCredentials(), config)
```

which will always read from app.config